# Android LinearLayout element's position

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

In Android how can I specify the space of the inner LinearLayout to let it takes the remain space as show in the picture?
I would to have an Image with fixed size as first and third element and in the middle a LinearLayout to take remain space.
Don't consider eventually margin/padding.
(picture is not in scale)

Comment: Just like the answer on the linked duplicate, but since your `LinearLayout` is horizontal, the middle's `layout_width` would be `0dp`, instead of its `layout_height`. Its `layout_weight` would still be just `1`.

Comment: thank you, it works